# Nullable properties vs. Nullable local variables

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

I am puzzled by the following behavior of `Nullable` types:

```
class TestClass {
    public int? value = 0;
}

TestClass test = new TestClass();
```

Now, `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(test.value)` returns the underlying `Nullable` type, which is `int`.
However, if I try to obtain the field type like this

```
FieldInfo field = typeof(TestClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)[0];
```

and I invoke

```
Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(field.FieldType).ToString()
```

it returns a `System.Nullable[System.Int32]` type. So that means the method `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()` has a different behavior depending on how you obtain the member type. Why is that so? If I simply use `test.value` how can I tell that it's `Nullable` without using reflection?

Comment: Is `typeof(field.FieldType) == typeof(test.value)`? I would imagine that since the method is called `GetUnderlyingType`, it acts differently for a type and an instance of a type.

Comment: Nope, `typeof(field.FieldType)` returns `Nullable<int>`, while `typeof(test.value)` simply returns `System.Int32` -- I'm asking, why are they returning different types? And, furthermore, how can you check if `test.value` is a `Nullable`?

Comment: Did you try `test.value is Nullable<int>`? Try for `int` as well to make sure that it doesn't give false positives. The strange behavior IMO comes from the strange fact that `typeof(test.value)` returns `System.Int32` and not `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: `test.value` always returns, by definition, an `int`.

Comment: What do you mean? `test.value is Nullable<int>` is a check that returns a `bool` that indicates whether `test.value` is an instance of `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are right `test.value is Nullable<int>` returns true! Then, why is the `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()` behavior different?

Comment: Well.. It returns the type that the Nullability encapsulates, doesn't it? `Nullable<int>` wraps around `int`, so it would return `int`. Maybe since the type `Nullable<int>` isn't itself encapsulated as a Nullable type (such as an imaginable `Nullable<Nullable<int>>`), the `GetUnderlyingType` doesn't really "bypass" the Nullability, and simply returns the type itself.

Comment: Try `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(new Person())`, where `Person` is some class that has nothing to do with `Nullable<T>`. Does it return `Person`?

Comment: `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(new Person().GetType())` returns null.

Comment: Well, it was a silly test anyway. We can't know how the developers chose to handle non-nullable types. Strange behaviors appear here and there, but so far there have always been ways to bypass them or adjust to them. So, has you problem been solved by using the `is` operator?

Comment: Write an answer that I can use to test both locals and member variables and you got it :)

Comment: There are actually better answers now, explaining the phenomena. Just glad to help with the solution :)

Comment: @YoryeNathan, as you can see in the link in my answer, the is operator treats the value as its underlying type.

Comment: @smartcaveman Meaning that it will indeed return false positives... So the only way is via Reflection? That sounds absurd. What if I got it as a parameter boxed as object? No way of knowing that I'm getting a `Nullable<int>` and not an `int`?

Comment: @YoryeNathan , i'm afraid so.  i'm not sure "false positive" is technically accurate, since this behavior is by design, but i certainly understand why you describe it as absurd.  all languages have their limitations.  if you want more info, follow the link to the programming guide at msdn

Comment: @smartcaveman Good thing I never bumped into this case. Can't imagine why I'd want to check the type of a local variable, though, so I suppose I won't be bumping into it in the future either. Reflection is good enough, to solve the issue when the nullable type is a member of a class.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, its hard to say.  i could imagine some difficulty with BlockExpression driven code-generators...but i haven't tried..just a thought

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nullable types are a little bit weird.  However, at least their behavior is well documented.

From the C# programming guide on MSDN, 
"How to: Identify Nullable Types"at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789(VS.80).aspx :

> You can also use the classes and methods of the System.Reflection namespace to generate Type objects that represent Nullable types. However, if you attempt to obtain type information from Nullable variables at runtime using the GetType method or the is operator, the result is a Type object that represents the underlying type, not the Nullable type itself.
> 
>
> Calling GetType on a Nullable type causes a boxing operation to be performed when the type is implicitly converted to Object. Therefore GetType always returns a Type object that represents the underlying type, not the Nullable type.

It's worth pointing out that the distinction in your headline is inaccurate.  The type behavior is not distinct based on local variables or properties, but on whether the type is accessed via a runtime object or by reflection (or use of the typeof operator).  Your inference is understandable, since the types of local variables are usually only accessed by means of a runtime object, however, it is flawed, because if you access a nullable object at runtime via a property accessor then its behavior will be equivalent to that of a local variable.

Also, to answer the last part of your question explicitly: **the only way to tell that test.value is nullable without using reflection would be to access it and get a NullReferenceException** (which, of course, can only happen if test.value is null.  As written, in your example, **the value is not null, so determining this without reflection would be impossible**

Comment: Thank you for providing the actual test procedure!

Answer (score 12):

smartcaveman's answer is the best one here so far in that it actually identifies the section of the documentation that describes this behaviour.

The behaviour is undesirable and unfortunate; it is due to the behaviour in combination of three features which, by themselves, behave reasonably.

The three features are:

- `GetType` is a non-virtual method; it cannot be overridden. This should make sense; an object doesn't get to decide what its type is reported as. By making it non-virtual, the method is guaranteed to tell the truth.
- The `this` value passed to a non-virtual method declared on `object` must be converted to `object`; therefore in the case of objects of value type, the receiver of the call to `GetType()` is boxed to `object`.
- Nullable value types have no boxed form; when you box a nullable int, you either get a boxed int or you get a null reference. You never get a valid reference to a boxed nullable int.

Each feature is reasonable on its own but in combination the result is undesirable: when you call `GetType` on a valid nullable int, the runtime boxes the nullable int to a boxed int and then passes that as the `this` of `object.GetType` which of course reports `int`. If the value is a null nullable int, the runtime boxes to null and then invokes `GetType` on a null reference and crashes. Neither of these behaviours are desirable, but we're stuck with them.

Comment: thank you.  I've read a lot of criticism about how .NET addresses nulls in general (not just nullables).  e.g. I'm sure you've heard it said that the fact that default(object) == null is an inherent flaw.  Is there any place where you have specifically addressed this contention, and the underlying reason for the design decision?

Comment: @smartcaveman: What else would you pick for `default(object)`? If you hate `null`, feel free to use Jon Skeet's `NonNullable<T>` .

Comment: @Brian: For class types it would be nice to have a default that was a bit more meaningful. The empty string and a readonly empty list are better defaults for `string` and `List<T>` than `null`. (Though it is hard to say what to do with interfaces and delegates.) It's interesting to contrast traditional OOP languages with prototype inheritance languages in this regard.

Comment: @Brian, I would go with something like `new {}`, but ideally it would be interned so you would always get the same reference.  I'm sure Eric has given this a lot more though than I.  I also think it would be really cool if you could configure defaults for interfaces and delegates through some sort of native IoC... it seems like the default for an unconfigured delegate would ideally do nothing, then return the default value for the return type (if not void).  The same type of approach could be taken with interfaces. (this is obviously all impossible at this stage in the game, of course)

Comment: The problem is essentially that "default" means "how should a field or array element of this type be initialized by the memory allocator", which is not actually *semantically* the default.

Comment: @EricLippert thank you for the insight. It is indeed the case that all of these features are reasonable, yet, when put together they create somewhat of an inconsistency.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're assuming that the `Type` of `test.value` is the same as the `Type` of the `field.FieldType` of `value`, and it's not.  Getting the `Type` of `test.value` actually gets the `Type` of what is stored in the field, in this case a 0.

`Type t = test.value.GetType()`

is the same (in your example) as

`Type t = 0.GetType()`

To demonstrate, initialize `value` to null and `test.value.GetType()` will throw a `NullReferenceException`

Answer (score 0):

Method GetNulllableUnderlyingType returns Underlying type for nullable types, for another types returns null;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetNulllableUnderlyingType(new TestClass().value));
        Console.WriteLine(GetNulllableUnderlyingType(new TestClass()));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int? value;
    }

    public static Type GetNulllableUnderlyingType<T>(T value)
    {
        Type result =  Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof (T));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I used the wrong `BindingFlags` in the example, but I used the right one in the code I was testing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: But I stil have correct output. I still sure something wrong in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(test.value)` in your example will not compile. Or `typeof(test.value)` as I have seen in comments.

Lets answer this by the following modified code:

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();
Type type1 = test.value.GetType(); // Gets the type of the data inside the field ==> System.Int32.
Type underlyingType1 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type1); // Gets the underlying type of System.Int32 ==> null.

FieldInfo field = typeof(TestClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)[0];
Type type2 = field.FieldType; // Now the type is retrieved of the field, not the data inside. ==> System.Int32?
Type underlyingType2 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type2); // Gets the underlying type of System.Int32? ==> System.Int32.
```

When you do a `GetType()` on a field, you will get the type of the data inside, not the type of the field itself. For example:

```
object o = 1;
Type type = o.GetType();
```

In this example, when you call `GetType()`, you also will get `System.Int32`, and not `System.Object`. Because in your your start with different types before calling `GetUnderylingType`, you end up with different results.