# GetType() can lie?

Tags: c#, types

Based on the following question asked a few days ago in SO: [GetType() and polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679239/gettype-and-polymorphism) and reading [Eric Lippert's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679239/gettype-and-polymorphism/16681120) answer, I started thinking if making `GetType()` not be virtual really ensured that an object could not lie about its `Type`.

Specifically, Eric's answer states the following:

> The framework designers are not going to add an incredibly dangerous feature such as allowing an object to lie about its type merely to make it consistent with three other methods on the same type.

Now the question is: can I make an object that *does* lie about its type without it being immediately obvious? I may be profoundly wrong here and I'd love clarification if that is the case, but consider the following code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    Type GetType();
}
```

And the following two implementations of said interface:

```
public class BadFoo : IFoo
{
    Type IFoo.GetType()
    {
        return typeof(int);
    }
}

public class NiceFoo : IFoo
{
}
```

Then if you run the following simple program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IFoo badFoo = new BadFoo();
    IFoo niceFoo = new NiceFoo();
    Console.WriteLine("BadFoo says he's a '{0}'", badFoo.GetType().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("NiceFoo says he's a '{0}'", niceFoo.GetType().ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Sure enough `badFoo` outputs an erroneous `Type`.

Now I don't know if this has any serious implications based on Eric describing this behavior as an "*incredibly dangerous feature*", but could this pattern pose a credible threat?

Comment: interesting title and topic!

Comment: `IFoo.GetType` and `object.GetType` is not the same thing so nothing bad is happening here except poor style. Edit: Generally `GetType` will be called on some object not known at compile-time, in most cases `object` and not some dodgy interface. :)

Comment: Your title sir, made my day.

Comment: If you do the same thing but call GetType() with them being `object`s, not `IFoo`s, does it still get a chance to lie?

Comment: You just introduce ***new*** members also called `GetType`, with the same signature. That does not relate to the `GetType` method which is important. You could also make a public instance method which hides the relevant `GetType` method, using the `new` modifier keyword. Note, if you have a generic method like `static Type Test<T>(T t) { return t.GetType(); }` (with no constraint on `T`), then stuff like `Test<IFoo>(new BadFoo())` will still call the original `GetType` method.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: This code gives no warning

Comment: This is a [rhetorical question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question), so ive voted to close as NARQ (as thats in the description of NARQ)

Comment: the GetType() is a lie!

Comment: @Jamiec - The question "could this pattern pose a credible threat?" isn't rhetorical.

Comment: @leppie: Allthough I mostly agree with you, there are cases where you could be iterating an IFoo typed collection and then based on the real type of the object have to do something particular to that type as the collection can respresent very different objects that have no commonality barring the interface. I know it's not a desirable pattern, and its probable bad code smell but in some cases you are stuck with it.

Comment: @MartinSmith - taken in isolation, you're right. But the whole question begs the question itself, which is rhetorical IMO.

Comment: `((object)badFoo).GetType()` is the only way to be sure what's the type of an object.

Comment: @leppie meh... I've just noticed that your comment had already explained the point I was trying to make in my answer more clearly and in only two and a half lines of text

Comment: With your code, putting the mouse pointer over `GetType` gives a tooltip of '`Type IFoo.GetType()`'. I don't know if this meets your criteria for "without it being immediately obvious".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Nice question! The way I see it, you could only really mislead a fellow developer if GetType was virtual on object, which it isn't.

What you did is akin to shadowing GetType, like this:

```
public class BadFoo
{
    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return typeof(int);
    }
}
```

with this class (and using [the sample code from the MSDN for the GetType() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx)) you could indeed have:

```
int n1 = 12;
BadFoo foo = new BadFoo();

Console.WriteLine("n1 and n2 are the same type: {0}",
                  Object.ReferenceEquals(n1.GetType(), foo.GetType())); 
// output: 
// n1 and n2 are the same type: True
```

so, yikes, you've successfully lied, right?
Well, yes and no... Consider that using this as an exploit would mean using your BadFoo instance as an argument to a method somewhere, that expects likely an `object` or a common base type for a hierarchy of objects. Something like this:

```
public void CheckIfInt(object ob)
{
    if(ob.GetType() == typeof(int))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("got an int! Initiate destruction of Universe!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("not an int");
    }
}
```

but `CheckIfInt(foo)` prints "not an int".

So, basically (back to your example), you could really only exploit your "lying type" with code that someone wrote against your `IFoo` interface, which is very explicit about the fact that it has a "custom" `GetType()` method.

Only if GetType() was virtual on object you would be able to craft a "lying" type that could be used with methods like `CheckIfInt` above to create havoc in libraries written by someone else.

Comment: yeah, its exactly the same as shadowing. The last paragraph is what really makes it obvious that there is really no threat. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

There are two ways of being sure about the Type:

1. Use `typeof` on the Type which can't be overloaded

   > ```
   > IFoo badFoo = new BadFoo();
   > IFoo niceFoo = new NiceFoo();
   >
   > Console.WriteLine("BadFoo says he's a '{0}'", badFoo.GetType().ToString());
   > Console.WriteLine("NiceFoo says he's a '{0}'", niceFoo.GetType().ToString());
   >
   > Console.WriteLine("BadFoo really is a '{0}'", typeof(BadFoo));
   > Console.WriteLine("NiceFoo really is a '{0}'", typeof(NiceFoo));
   > Console.ReadLine();
   > ```
2. Cast the instance to an `object` and call the `GetType()` Method

   > ```
   > IFoo badFoo = new BadFoo();
   > IFoo niceFoo = new NiceFoo();
   >
   > Console.WriteLine("BadFoo says he's a '{0}'", badFoo.GetType().ToString());
   > Console.WriteLine("NiceFoo says he's a '{0}'", niceFoo.GetType().ToString());
   >
   > Console.WriteLine("BadFoo really is a '{0}'", ((object)badFoo).GetType());
   > Console.WriteLine("NiceFoo really is a '{0}'", ((object)niceFoo).GetType());
   > Console.ReadLine();
   > ```

Comment: How will you use `typeof` in a method that only gets a `IFoo badFoo` as parameter?

Comment: `typeof` can't be applied to instances of a class which is what we need to do here. Your only option is `GetType()`.

Comment: Your two samples are doing two different things.  The second lines don't answer the question required - they explicitly "get the type `BadFoo`" but they don't "get the type of variable `badFoo`."

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry. As usual I did not read the question carefully enough. I updated my answer to point out the two different ways of being sure about the type.

Comment: of course you're "sure" about the type with `typeof`, since you're explicitly giving it the type. the point of the question is asking a reference of which you don't know the actual type what type it is. the second example is a better fit.

Comment: This is what I was pointing out. So what is the point of your comment? :)

Answer (score 10):

No, you can't make GetType lie. You are only introducing a new method. Only code that are aware of this method will call it.

You cannot for example make third-party or framework code call your new GetType method instead of the real one, since that code does not know that your method exists and will therefore never call it.

You can however confuse your own developers with such a declaration. Any code that is compiled with your declaration and that use parameters or variables typed as IFoo or any type derived from that will indeed use your new method instead. But since that only affects your own code it does not really impose a "threat".

If you do want to provide a custom type description for a class this should be done using a [Custom Type Descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171819.aspx), perhaps by annotating your class with a [TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionproviderattribute.aspx). This can be useful in some situations.

Comment: +1 for your second paragraph explicitly pointing out that 3rd-party code doesn't know about a custom GetType implementation. Other answers hinted at that idea but didn't really come out and say it (at least not as clearly).

Answer (score 7):

Well, actually there *is* already a type which can lie in `GetType`: any nullable type.

[This code](https://ideone.com/PSPKTt):

```
int? x = 0; int y = 0;
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType() == y.GetType());
```

outputs `True`.

---

Actually, it's not the `int?` who is lying, just implicit cast to `object` turns `int?` into a boxed `int`. But nevertheless you *cannot* tell `int?` from `int` with `GetType()`.

Comment: Which is expected (or at least well-known) behavior. The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381559) explains this concept pretty clearly, as well as the reason for it.

Comment: @brichins: Well, I agree it's known, but I cannot agree it's _well_-known. Anyway, this is a case where `GetType()` produces somewhat strange result. I have actually asked several colleagues about whether a non-shadowed `GetType()` can return something which differs from the actual object's runtime type, everyone's answer was 'no'.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it will, since every library code that calls GetType will declare the variable as 'Object' or as a Generic type 'T'

The following code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo badFoo = new BadFoo();
        IFoo niceFoo = new NiceFoo();
        PrintObjectType("BadFoo", badFoo);
        PrintObjectType("NiceFoo", niceFoo);
        PrintGenericType("BadFoo", badFoo);
        PrintGenericType("NiceFoo", niceFoo);
    }

    public static void PrintObjectType(string actualName, object instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object {0} says he's a '{1}'", actualName, instance.GetType());
    }

    public static void PrintGenericType<T>(string actualName, T instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Type {0} says he's a '{1}'", actualName, instance.GetType());
    }
```

prints:

> Object BadFoo says he's a 'TypeConcept.BadFoo'
>
> Object NiceFoo says he's a 'TypeConcept.NiceFoo'
>
> Generic Type BadFoo says he's a 'TypeConcept.BadFoo'
>
> Generic Type NiceFoo says he's a 'TypeConcept.NiceFoo'

The only time this kind of code will result in bad scenario's is in your own code, where you declare the parameter type as IFoo

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo badFoo = new BadFoo();
        IFoo niceFoo = new NiceFoo();
        PrintIFoo("BadFoo", badFoo);
        PrintIFoo("NiceFoo", niceFoo);
    }

    public static void PrintIFoo(string actualName, IFoo instance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IFoo {0} says he's a '{1}'", actualName, instance.GetType());
    }
```

> IFoo BadFoo says he's a 'System.Int32'
>
> IFoo NiceFoo says he's a 'TypeConcept.NiceFoo'

Answer (score 4):

Worst that can happen as far as I can tell is misleading innocent programmers who happen to use the poisoned class, for example:

```
Type type = myInstance.GetType();
string fullName = type.FullName;
string output;
if (fullName.Contains(".Web"))
{
    output = "this is webby";
}
else if (fullName.Contains(".Customer"))
{
    output = "this is customer related class";
}
else
{
    output = "unknown class";
}
```

If `myInstance` is instance of a class such as you describe in the question, it will just be treated as unknown type.

So my answer is no, can't see any real threat here.

Comment: Sure. A careful programmer can see at compile-time which method "GetType" he invokes. `Object.GetType()` is distinct from `SomeUserdefinedInterfaceClassOrStruct.GetType()`. Only, if you use the `dynamic` type, you can never know what will happen at binding-time. So you should use `dynamic x = expression; ... Type t = ((object)x).GetType();` in cases like that.

Comment: @Jeppe fair points! I think it justifies separate answer, my answer focus more on "innocent" programmer who won't be so careful.

Answer (score 3):

You have some options if you want to play safe against that kind of hack:

**Cast to object first**

You can call the original `GetType()` method by first casting the instance to an `object`:

```
 Console.WriteLine("BadFoo says he's a '{0}'", ((object)badFoo).GetType());
```

results in:

```
BadFoo says he's a 'ConsoleApplication.BadFoo'
```

**Use template method**

Using this template method will also give you the real type:

```
static Type GetType<T>(T obj)
{
    return obj.GetType();
}

GetType(badFoo);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between `object.GetType` and `IFoo.GetType`. `GetType` is called at compile time on not known objects, an not on Interfaces. In your example, with output `badFoo.GetType` it is expected bahaviour, because you overload the method. Only thing is, that other programmers can get confused of this behaviour.

But if you use `typeof()` it will output that the type is the same, and you can't overwrite `typeof()`.

Also the programmer can see at compile time, which method `GetType` he invokes.

So to your question: This pattern can not pose a credible threat, but it is also not best style of coding.

Comment: `badFoo.GetType()` IS expected behavior, because `GetType` was overloaded.